# How can I convert this SQL query to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

```
public class Inventory
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal PurchasePrice { get; set; }
        public decimal ResellerPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }
        public byte FundSource { get; set; } 
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }

}

public class InventoryEvent
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
        public decimal? Total { get; set; }
        public byte EventType { get; set; }
        public byte? PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this in LINQ,

```
select A.Id, sum(A.Quantity) as totalQuantity, 
  (totalQuantity - 
    (select sum(B.Quantity) 
     from InventoryEvent B 
     where B.ProductId = A.ProductId and B.LocationId = A.LocationId 
     group by B.ProductId, B.LocationId)
  ) as Available 
from Inventory A 
group by A.ProductId, A.LocationId
```

I want to display the columns in Inventory A after grouping by `ProductId` and `LocationId`, with 2 additional columns; `sum(A.Quantity)` and `(sum(A.Quantity) - sum(B.Quantity))` and a the same time eagerload `A.Product` and `A.Location`

I tried this

```
var inventories = AppContext.Inventories.Include(i => i.Product)
            .Include(i => i.Location)
            .GroupBy(i => new { i.LocationId, i.ProductId });
```

but I don't know how to move forward and not even sure if it's correct.

Comment: Are you sure SQL is correct? `A.Id` is not a part of `group by A.ProductId, A.LocationId` statement.

Comment: You can use tool like linqpad which will automatically convert your sql query to linq.
Check out this link https://www.linqpad.net/ for more details.

Comment: thanks for sharing this tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select SUM you can not display Id of single object.
You can display ProductId and LocationId (columns on which you are grouping).
I am not sure if you need to Include Product or Location if you refer to ProductId and LocationId only.

Try something like this (not tested):

```
var inventories = AppContext.Inventories.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductId, x.LocationId }).Select(g => new
                {
                    g.Key.ProductId,
                    g.Key.LocationId,
                    totalQuantity = g.Sum(y => y.Quantity),
                    Available = g.Sum(y => y.Quantity) - AppContext.InventoryEvents.Where(e => e.ProductId == g.Key.ProductId && e.LocationId == g.Key.LocationId).Sum(x => x.Quantity)
                });
```